# organize posts by brand or title, something other than id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a menu, and in this menu there is an option to select posts which have a certain brand name in the database. When clicked no the brand name in the menu I want the user to be directed to the page which has posts with only that brand name in the database.

This is my button url:

```
        <a href="brands.php?brand=ALange&Söhne">A. Lange & Söhne</a>
```

This is my sql call:

```
if($_GET){
$id1 = $_GET['id'];
        $id1 = (int) $id1;
$sql = "SELECT posts.id AS postid, 
        category.id AS catid,
        category.catname,
        posts.id,
        posts.cat_id,
        posts.brand,
        posts.auction,
        posts.likes,
        posts.image,
        posts.title,
        posts.textbody,
        posts.author,
        posts.postdate
        FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON category.id= posts.cat_id WHERE         (posts.brand ='$brand')";
//"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$id1' ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
//get set above for ID
} 
else if(!$_GET){
$sql = "SELECT posts.id AS postid, 
        category.id AS catid,
        category.catname,
        posts.id,
        posts.cat_id,
        posts.brand,
        posts.auction,
        posts.likes,
        posts.image,
        posts.title,
        posts.textbody,
        posts.author,
        posts.postdate
        FROM posts INNER JOIN category ON category.id= posts.cat_id WHERE       (posts.brand ='$brand') ORDER BY postdate DESC";
```

It doesnt seem to be working. how can I get the user to go to a list of posts with only one chosen brand. Right now it displays the two posts I have where the BRAND section is left black in the database.

Comment: What isn't working? You are getting the wrong results? You get nothing? You get an error?

Comment: I get only two results, both are not in the chosen brand.

Comment: Have you tried to run this query directly in mysql? does it give you the same results?

Comment: this SQL runs perfectly.   SELECT posts.id AS postid, category.id AS catid, category.catname, posts.id, posts.cat_id, posts.brand, posts.auction, posts.likes, posts.image, posts.title, posts.textbody, posts.author, posts.postdate
FROM posts
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = posts.cat_id
WHERE (
posts.brand =  'ALange&Söhne'

Comment: then post more of your code, you're probably running the wrong query.

Comment: Be careful with "brand" with ampresand in it like shown.  You need to url-encode that ampersand, otherwise the receiving script would interpret the `&Söhne` as not part of "brand" value, but as a new parameter.

Comment: thanks, i removed the & but i am still getting the same two results (the posts with no brand )

Comment: so at what point did you set `$brand = $_GET['brand'];`? because I don't see it.

Comment: that hasnt been set. should i set that on the page called brands? or on the page containing the link to brands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from looking at this, it looks like you are not grabbing the GET data.  You are sending the query string "?brand=ALange&Söhne" but your GET is looking for "id" instead.

What happens if you change your PHP to:

```
$brand = $_GET['brand'];
```

Not sure if you have anything else passed via GET, though.  Hope that helps you out.

--Charles

Comment: Sorry, that should have been  $brand = $_GET['brand'];

Answer (score 2):

Since you aren't setting `$brand = $_GET['brand']` it's actually just doing this in your sql query `WHERE (posts.brand = '')` make sure you set the variable if you want it to work.

Comment: should i put that above my sql or below it?

Comment: its these exotic characters!!! the umlaut and things like that, i guess i can only use english alphabet characters and numbers

Comment: it should be put above. consider using pdo as well so you can use prepared statements that would make it likely work.

Comment: I agree with @Augwa, about PDO.  I would put it by the $id1 = $_GET['id'];